# How do I create a RewriteCond for when the query string contains "*" or "?"

Tags: 302-redirect, query-string

If query string contains "star symbol" or `?` then I need to redirect to other page, how to check in the following condition that thequery string contains "star symbol" or `?`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q={star symbol,?}
```